# Are the chosen anime within Welcome To The N.H.K. of any significance?

Tags: welcome-to-the-nhk

In the anime of *Welcome To the NHK*, the show that is constantly played nextdoor is *Puru Puru Pururin*.

[image: Purupuru Pururin~]

We know this character is not from a real show [(although it has a website alluding to this)](http://web.archive.org/web/20160923135640/http://www.kadokawa.co.jp/hikky/plrin/index.php), so it's not an external influence.

In the manga, an *Ojya the witch* is mentioned, along with lyrics from the relevant show:

> Please give me the courage in my heart to help me fold away this carpet of sadness and discover the me inside,
>
> Oh yes, the delicate heart of a lady,
>
> Just look in my eyes and tell me you love me,
>
> It's like a fairy tail
>
> ...

Do we know if this is an actual show? If so, is it of any relevance?

In the light novel, the show that is played constantly is *Ojamajo Doremi* (or *Magical DoReMi* in English) and a life-size figurine is introduced from *Martian Successor Nadesico*

> Yamizaki declares that the figurine is God and tries to convince Satou to worship it.

[image: Magical DoReMi]
[image: Martian Successor Nadesico]

Do the choice of these shows have any significance?  Are there any (rough) similarities in plot to Welcome to the NHK?

**TL;DR - Do we know the show that was in the manga, Do the shows in the light novel have any meaning or were they just chosen arbitrarily?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It always reminded me of [Di Gi Charat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Di_Gi_Charat) ("Dejiko") but I don't have any evidence that this was intentional. Visually they're pretty similar, and both are sort of used as mascots (Di Gi Charat being the mascot for the Broccoli gaming company). They also both append random words to the end of their sentences (e.g. "purin"). Additionally, according to Wikipedia:

> An animated Dejiko and her sidekick Gema first appeared on in a television advertisement for Gamers, set to the store's theme song, **Welcome!** by Hiroko Kato

[image]

But again, don't know any official source that says one way or another about the similarity.